# NSURL parameterString with .NET service call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wcf

I'm tring to use the NSURL class's parameterString message to return the string from the following url:

```
http://www.host.com/Api/Service.svc/GetStuff?param=thisIsTheParamValue
```

I keep getting `nil` for the parameterString. Does that url not conform to the standards that Apple uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL doesn't conform to the standard NSURL uses for parameterString. NSURL uses [RFC 1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt) standard, which defines the parameter string as ";" params. Use the [query](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/query) message instead to get the string after the '?'.